# VBA Runtime Error 438 at newWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B2").Paste, can't figure out why

Tags: excel, vba, export, new-operator

Keep getting the error as said above at the line `newWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B2").Paste` however this works `newWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Paste`

```
Sub CopyVisibleCellsExport()
    Dim selectedRange As Range
    Dim visibleRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim newWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim saveLocation As String
    
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    
    ' Get the last row with a number in column Z
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Get the range from B10 to Z:lastRow
    Set selectedRange = Range("B10:Z" & lastRow)
    
    ' Get the visible cells in the selected range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set visibleRange = selectedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Copy the visible cells to the clipboard
    If Not visibleRange Is Nothing Then
        visibleRange.Copy
    End If
    
    ' Create a new workbook and paste the copied cells with all formatting at B2
    Set newWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
    'On Error GoTo PasteError
    'newWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Paste
    newWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B2").Paste
    'newWorkbook.Worksheets(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
    
    ' Resize the columns and rows to fit the content
    newWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
    newWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.AutoFit
    
    ' Resize column A and the last empty column to be 10
    'newWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 10
    'lastCol = newWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1
    'newWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Columns(lastCol).ColumnWidth = 10
    
    ' Fit the columns to an A4 sheet width
    newWorkbook.Worksheets(1).PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
    
    ' Save the new workbook as a new file in the same folder as the main file with xlsx extension and format
    saveLocation = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\New Workbook " & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy") & " " & Format(Time, "hhmmss") & ".xlsx"
    
    ' Close the new workbook
    newWorkbook.Close
    
    ' Clear the clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    'Protect sheet again
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
    
Exit Sub

'PasteError:
'    MsgBox "An error occurred while pasting. Please check the following:" & vbNewLine & _
'           "- The property or method you are using is valid and supported by the object." & vbNewLine & _
'           "- The object reference is correct and matches the expected object type." & vbNewLine & _
'           "- The library references are not missing or broken.", vbCritical, "Paste Error"
    
End Sub
```

Expecting to paste it at B2 and do the formatting as coded

Comment: Use `PasteSpecial` with a range.

Comment: @Rory something like this?

newWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B2")PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

Comment: I would suggest you move the `End If` to before `Exit Sub`

Comment: Yes, but with a full stop before the `PasteSpecial` ;)

Comment: Thanks Rory I did get this working yesterday with the PasteSpecial method